# Making own shell in C

Tags: c, shell, operating-system, posix

I'm trying to make my own shell in C, but am having trouble with strtok.  I use it to correctly parse out the command and arguments from the input, but I can't get it to parse the path (it currently segfaults).  Once I get the path parsed correctly I should be able to call execlp on each piece and fork processes accordingly.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated, code is below.  Also feel free to comment on style choices too if you think there is something I could be doing better.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

void parse(char *, char *);
void process(char *, char *, int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *command;
  char *path;
  char buffer[1024];
  command = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
  path = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
  int loop = 1;
  while(loop == 1){
    path = getenv("MYPATH");
    if(path == NULL)
      path = "/bin#.";
    printf("($MYPATH is %s)\n", path);

    printf("myshell$ ");
    command = fgets(buffer, 1024, stdin);
    printf("Buffer: %s", buffer);
    printf("Command: %s", command);

    if(strcmp(command,"exit\n") == 0 || strcmp(command, "quit\n") == 0){
      loop = 0;
      printf("Program Terminated\n");
    }
    parse(command, path);
  }
  return 0;
}

void parse(char *command, char *path){
  char *argv;
  int argNum = 0;
  argv = strtok(command, " ");
  while(argv != NULL){
    printf("%s %d\n", argv, argNum);
    argv = strtok (NULL, " ");
    argNum++;
    }
  printf("Calling...\n");
  process(argv, path, argNum);
  printf("Called\n");
}

void process(char *argv, char *path, int argNum){
  char *pathPiece;
  int pathNum = 0;
  pathPiece = strtok(path, "#");
  while(pathPiece != NULL){
    printf("%s %d\n", pathPiece, pathNum);
    pathPiece = strtok(NULL, "#");
    pathNum++;
  }
}
```

Comment: What inputs are you feeding it when it segfaults?

Comment: [Don't cast `malloc` in C](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html).  It hides bugs such as these.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting path to point to a read-only memory location, and calling `strtok` on it is probably the cause of your problems when `strtok` attempts to tokenize it (i.e. write a null character somewhere inside it).

You probably need something like:

```
char path[1024];
```

and call `strcpy` like:

```
strcpy(path, getenv("MYPATH"));
```

and

```
strcpy(path, "/bin#.");
```

I strongly suggest you read up on string handling in C.

Comment: Thanks, helps a lot. I do know the string functions though sometimes my C++ sneaks in (I'm newer to C) and I have a hard time seeing the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The following wont have the desired effect

```
path = "/bin#.";
```

Try `strcpy( path, "/bin#." );` instead.

And, as larsmans said, fix up the malloc so that you're allocating enough bytes for the size of a command.

Also, if its C you're strictly compiling for, then you should have a compile error when declaring the `loop` integer in the position you are.

Comment: Thanks, I should have noticed that (sometimes my C++ sneaks in and I'm newer to C).  I think the new C standard now allows you to declare integers after executing code, I could be wrong though.

Comment: @fossuser: Yes, modern C does allow variable declarations after executable code. Many of us C programmers forget that though, since we have to maintain code written with prehistoric compilers.